# Method that outputs figure

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write a method that outputs the following figure:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I tried everything but my code always outputs this instead:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Here is my code:

```
public void outputFigure(int y) {
    count1 = y;
    count2 = y;
    int spaces = 0;
    int x = y;
    int x2 = y;
    boolean s = false;
    while (s != true) {
        for (int i = spaces; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        spaces++;
        if (spaces == y - 1) {
            s = true;
        }

        for (count2 = 0; count2 < x; count2++) {
            for (count1 = 0; count1 < x2; count1++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            x2--;

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem, can you [accept one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

Too many loops; you need an outer loop `i` from `0` to `y` (the # of lines). Then a loop from `i` to `y - 1` for spaces and another one from `y - i - 1` to `y` for stars. Then a new-line. Also, no need for an instance here; so we can make the method `static`. Like,

```
public static void outputFigure(int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < y - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = (y - i - 1); j < y; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

There is repetitious code here though, which violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle; let's refactor that - first a method to repeat a `String` an arbitrary `count`, there are many ways to do that. One (using Java 8+) would be

```
private static String repeat(String str, int count) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> str).limit(count).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Then we can use that to generate the figure. Like,

```
public static void outputFigure(int y) {
    IntStream.range(0, y).forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.printf(
                    "%s%s%n", repeat(" ", y - i - 1), repeat("*", i + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Elliott Frisch pointed out, here's another version:

```
       for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 5; j >= 1; j--)
            {
                if (j <= i)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
```

You only actually need to do two loops.

Also, one quick stylistic point: don't explicitly compare to `true` and `false`.

```
while (s != true)
```

can be simplified to

```
while (!s)
```

which is much "cleaner" and more concise.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, you may also want to consider using a more meaningful variable name than `s` - names like this can be very confusing for debugging (or if you or someone else has to modify the code later).

Comment: Even cleaner if using meaningful variable names. `s` doesn't say much actually.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza True - I edited to mention that the OP might want to consider a more meaningful name.